# get value of column when column name is based on the value of another column

Tags: r, get, data.table

I have a data table which contains one million records and I try to create a new column based on `month.idx`:

```
dt[, new_col := get(paset0("month_",month.idx)]
```

and it only works for the first line.

Can anyone help me with this problem? thanks!

```
Data
    id month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 month.idx
1:  x1       1       1       1       0       1         3
2:  x2       0       0       0       1       0         4
3:  x3       1       0       0       0       0         1
4:  x4       0       0       0       0       0         5
5:  x5       1       1       0       0       1         2
6:  x6       0       1       0       1       1         3
7:  x7       0       0       1       1       1         4
8:  x8       0       0       0       0       0         1
9:  x9       0       0       0       0       1         5

results:
    id month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 month.idx new_col
1:  x1       1       1       1       0       1         3       1
2:  x2       0       0       0       1       0         4       0
3:  x3       1       0       0       0       0         1       0
4:  x4       0       0       0       0       0         5       0
5:  x5       1       1       0       0       1         2       0
6:  x6       0       1       0       1       1         3       0
7:  x7       0       0       1       1       1         4       1
8:  x8       0       0       0       0       0         1       0
9:  x9       0       0       0       0       1         5       0

expected:
    id month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 month.idx new_col
1:  x1       1       1       1       0       1         3       1
2:  x2       0       0       0       1       0         4       1
3:  x3       1       0       0       0       0         1       1
4:  x4       0       0       0       0       0         5       0
5:  x5       1       1       0       0       1         2       1
6:  x6       0       1       0       1       1         3       0
7:  x7       0       0       1       1       1         4       0
8:  x8       0       0       0       0       0         1       0
9:  x9       0       0       0       0       1         5       1
```

Comment: It's generally helpful to provide and test code that reproduces the issue. (In this case, we don't have code to create the data.table and you didn't test and notice the typo paset0) If interested, eg for your next question, there's some guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 options:

**1)** Using `get` row by row taking in Frank’s comment:

```
DT[, new_col := get(paste0("month_", month.idx)), by= month.idx]
```

**2)** Melt and then join to do a lookup

```
DT[, variable := paste0("month_", month.idx)]
DT[melt(DT, id.vars="id", measure.vars=patterns("^month_")), 
    on=.(id, variable), new_col := value]
```

Speed is dependent on the number of rows & month columns that you have.

data:

```
DT <- fread("id month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 month.idx
x1       1       1       1       0       1         3
x2       0       0       0       1       0         4
x3       1       0       0       0       0         1
x4       0       0       0       0       0         5
x5       1       1       0       0       1         2
x6       0       1       0       1       1         3
x7       0       0       1       1       1         4
x8       0       0       0       0       0         1")
```

Comment: Re speed, the first way might be faster if you group by month.idx instead of row (if there are many more rows than columns)